# Solve congruence using fermat's theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruences

Hi I am given this problem and I am supposed to use fermat's theorem.
Here is it is:
Prove that
$$24^{31} \equiv 23^{32} \pmod{19}$$

We are supposed to solve it by setting up the congruence like this:

$$24^{31} \equiv x \pmod{19}$$

$$23^{32} \equiv x \pmod{19}$$

I am just confused how to break it down. 
I was hoping someone can guide me through this question

Answer (score 1):

mod $\,19\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{24}\equiv \overbrace{ 5 \equiv \color{#c00}{4^{-1}}}^{\Large\!  5\,\cdot\, 4\,\equiv \,1 }\,$ so $\ 23^{32}\color{#c00}{24}^{-31}\!\equiv \overbrace{4^{32}(\color{#c00}{4^{-1}})^{-31}}^{\Large 4^{63}\,\equiv\,\ \color{#0a0}2^{\,\color{#0a0}{2\cdot 9}\,\cdot 7}}\!\equiv \color{#0a0}{(2^{18})}^7\equiv\color{#0a0}{(1)}^7\!\equiv 1\,$ by $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{Fermat}$

Comment: Don't I break up $24^{31}$ into smaller exponents?

Comment: @HG319 Are you asking about the above proof, or another way?

Comment: I guess I am asking if there is another way to prove it

Comment: so I understand that $5$ is the remainder of $24 mod 19$ but I do not understand why you do $5⋅4≡1$ to get $4^-1$. How come you cant solve each congruence separately and then see if the remainders are the same

Comment: when finding both $x$ for each congruence shouldn't they be the same value?

Comment: @HG319 I made the observation that $\,23,24 \equiv 4,5,\,$ and the latter is a pair of inverses since their product is one. Then, replacing $\,5\,$ by $\,4^{-1}\,$ we get an equation involving powers of a *single* number $\,4,\,$ so we can bring them all to one side of the equation, then use little Fermat to reduce the exponent, obtaining $1$, so both powers are equal, i.e. $\,4^{32} 4^{31}\equiv 1\,$ so $\, 4^{32}\equiv (4^{-1})^{31},\,$ so $\, 23^{32}\equiv 24^{31}\ $ by $\,4\equiv 23,\,$ $\,4^{-1}\equiv 5\equiv 24\ \ $

Comment: so what if I wanted to just prove $24^{31}≡x(mod19)$, what steps would I make?